# OpenGL image display in 3d space

Tags: python, opengl, texture-mapping

I would like to display an image onto a rectangle in 3d space with pyOpengl and pygame.

I don't mind if the image is disorted for now.
Here is my code with the few opengl functions that I know of for image display:

```
import pygame, OpenGL, math, numpy
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from PIL import Image #have Pillow instead of PIL

img = Image.open('myPixelArt.bmp')
img_data = numpy.array(list(img.getdata()), numpy.int8)
im = glGenTextures(1,img)
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,4)
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP)
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP)
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 5, GL_RGB, img.size[0], img.size[1], 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img_data)
gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, img.size[0], img.size[1], GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img_data );
def wall(image): #I would like the image on this wall
    glColor((1,0,0))
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,image) 
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glTexCoord2f(0,0)
    glVertex3f(-4,-4,-8)
    glTexCoord2f(1,0)
    glVertex3f(-4,4,-8)
    glTexCoord2f(1,1)
    glVertex3f(4,4,-8)
    glTexCoord2f(0,1)
    glVertex3f(4,-4,-8)
    glEnd()

def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = (600,600)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
main()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    glLoadIdentity()
    gluPerspective(45, 1, 0.05, 100)
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

    glTranslatef(0,0,-5)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    wall(im)

    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(50)
```

However, if i call wall(img) instead, I get

```
File "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\MattPython\Stackoverflow.py", line 19, in wall
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,image)
ArgumentError: argument 2: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Comment: Each vertex needs both its real-space coordinates (position) *and* the 2D texture coordinates to specify which part of the image they map to - to map the entire image to a rectangle, use (0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1).

Comment: Right, do you have to use a gl function with that? do you enter one 2d coordinate after one 3d coordinate, or do you do all four 3d coordinates then all four (or eight?) 2d coordinates?

Comment: You specify them before declaring each vertex... so glTexCoord2f for first vertex, glVertex3f for first vertex,... the same for second vertex... you don't have to use `3fv` version that accepts vectors, if you are specifying componencs, just use `3f`.

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work, I posted the new wall function as and edit; is this still wrong?

Comment: @MattMaich: Well, in your code, you call `wall(im)`, but the texture name is `img`? Is this a copy&paste error in the question, or some error in the code?

Comment: True, but now I fixed that and calling wall(img) gives an error. I also tried omitting the  im =  in line 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, fixed a few things:

1) needed to call `pygame.init()` and `pygame.display.set_mode` (which is `main()`) before `glGenTextures`.

2) used `pygame.image.load` instead of `Image.open`

3) used `pygame.image.tostring(img, "RGB", 1)` instead of `numpy.array(list(img.getdata()), numpy.int8)`

4) need to call `glBindTexture` before `glTexParameteri`

This is my working example:

```
import pygame, OpenGL
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

def main():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_mode((600,600), DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
main()

img = pygame.image.load('myPixelArt.bmp')
textureData = pygame.image.tostring(img, "RGB", 1)
width = img.get_width()
height = img.get_height()

im = glGenTextures(1)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, im)

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData)
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

def wall(image): 
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glTexCoord2f(0,0)
    glVertex3f(-4,-4,-16)
    glTexCoord2f(0,1)
    glVertex3f(-4,4,-16)
    glTexCoord2f(1,1)
    glVertex3f(4,4,-8)
    glTexCoord2f(1,0)
    glVertex3f(4,-4,-8)
    glEnd()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    glLoadIdentity()
    gluPerspective(45, 1, 0.05, 100)
    glTranslatef(0,0,-5)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    wall(im)

    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(50)
```